# Lazy Image Loading issue

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I have the following problem: I use react-lazy-load-image-component for lazy image loading. There are several Tabs on the page. On the first one, everything works as it should, and images are loaded as I scroll the page. On all subsequent Tabs, React believes that I have already scrolled to the bottom of the page and starts loading all the images at once. How do I fix it?

I am completely stuck.

Comment: Can you share your code or something that can help elaborate on your problem more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

When you switch tabs, the scroll position might not reset properly, causing the library to believe that you've already scrolled and triggering the loading of all images.

1:- This ensures that the scroll position is managed independently for each tab
2: -Ensure that when you switch tabs, the previous tab's component is unmounted. This helps in resetting the scroll position for each tab.
3:- You can manually reset the scroll position to the top of the tab content whenever a tab is selected.

if you clicked on tab then reset the scroll position

```
const scrollToTop = () => {document.getElementById("scroller").scroll(0,0)}
```

or

```
window.scrollto(0 0)
```